# Is Holocaust denial illegal in the West?

Tags: politics, world-war-ii

Living in the Middle East, I've had many discussions with fundamentalists and Islamists about freedom of speech. They have often claimed that freedom of speech in the West is a myth because denying the Holocaust took place is illegal.

Is that really the case in the West?

Comment: "The West" is too broad; it includes too many jurisdictions. The laws enacting and limiting the freedom of speech are very different in, for example, the USA, Germany and the UK. Please limit it to one country.

Comment: Some countries have explicit laws: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_against_Holocaust_denial

Comment: Some other countries (e.g. Canada) have/had other laws which may apply, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holocaust_denial#Z.C3.BCndel_trials

Comment: How is this "too broad"? That wikipedia link above basically answers the question. 16 out of 50 European countries and no countries outside of Europe (excluding Israel) have such a law. None of the English speaking countries (USA, UK, Australia, Ireland), being major representatives of "the West" have such a law as well...

Comment: @sashkello: Because Wikipedia isn't trustworthy enough, and to verify its claims would require checking each of its 75 references, which is, I think, too onerous for one question.

Comment: Although it seems too broad, I think there's a good reason for that with this question. Many Islamists make the same mistake by calling many countries the same thing (West). Ofcourse, the West does the same thing by calling many countries the Middle-East, which is only slightly better. In this dialogue, it's appropriate to be broad.

Comment: Perhaps you'd be best off going to Politics.SE and asking how many countries have these laws and how they can be justified in the context of free speech.

Comment: It is illegal in Germany. However, based on their history, German's consider anyone denying the holocaust to be a first rate asshole and putting them into jail as a public service, cleaning up the environment. It doesn't actually count as "speech" in the mind of a German, so it is no restriction on "free speech".

Comment: @Mast the issue with "too broad" questions is they take too big an answer to address. Checking 75 sources would indeed not be appropriate in an answer here. That said, I agree that this question is posed the only reasoably correct way - but we still can't address it.

Comment: @gnasher729, Could you please vlarify more how sending holocaust deniers into jail doesn't restrict free speech as I don't grasb your point well?

Comment: @Questioner the reason its illegal, is because of the sentiments in that country. free speech isnt about saying whatever you want, the idea behind free speech is that people are able to have rational discussions about politics, science, religion, without the government limiting them. Hate speech in almost every country is illegal(countries with free speech) these laws are in place because people miss use their words to intentionally hurt others. saying the holocaust didn't happen is done purely to incite others, not to have a reasonable discourse.

Comment: @Himarm Hate speech is illegal in many Western countries, but is perfectly legal in the US (where anti-hate-speech laws are routinely struck down).

Comment: @Himarm,Ok but from another perspective, Islamic fundamentalists in middle east could use similar argument to yours and say that the (islamic) community has a sentiment towards any criticise to Islam and hence, in countries where muslims form majority it's morally legal to prevent others from talking about islam in a way which muslims are not satisfied with. So they have the right to judge people for not believing more in islam because they have sentiments towards that! There is a similarity between what you say and what they say. Both of you make what's can be said is what socially accepted.

Comment: @Questioner free speech tends not to start radical, and it clearly follows public opinion, the vast majority of the public opinion in a country like germany is that its not okay to deny the holocaust. for an islamic country to implement free speech honestly we should expect them to include laws against bashing islam, because the overwhelming majority of the population would be against seeing things anti Islam. So yes it is hypocritical of someone who defends the holocaust, yet does not defend Islam, because its purely a local population sentiment.

Comment: @Himarm, I think that as a logical consequence of what you defend is that there is no such thing called, Human Rights which humanity should guarantee for people regardless of their race,sex or social background becuase rights of the person (specially, what it's allowed for her to say) depends mainly on what her society accepts. So, Human Rights are also myth we should give up.

Comment: @Questioner: The difference is that Islam is about a 1300 year old delusion while holocaust denial is about historical facts and the murder of tens of millions of people. The other difference is that the delusion is right now used as the justification of murder (100,000 or more murdered in Iraq over the last years, thousands murdered right now by Isis), while Germans want to do their best to prevent the reoccurrence of murderous history.

Comment: @gnasher729, If you think that saying islam is a delusion makes me angry, you're wrong because I'm not even a muslim "ex-muslim in fact".

Comment: @Oddthinking I've seen your assertion several times on this site, yet I don't understand it as there have been studies saying otherwise http://news.cnet.com/2100-1038_3-5997332.html

Comment: @Andy: This isn't the place to discuss this. See http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/973/23.

Comment: @Oddthinking The accepted answer seems to differ from your own answer on that question.  However it seems that you really don't want to discuss it at all as you've made up your mind that Wikipedia (or any encyclopedia) are never to be used, so I suppose there's no point in continuing regardless.

Comment: @Andy: I disagree with your appraisal of the situation, but again, this isn't the place to discuss this. You can take it to chat if you like.

Comment: @Questioner While there are some Western countries where lying about the holocaust is explicitly banned, there is a much bigger restriction on freedom of speech in most Western countries I know of, and pretty much all other countries too: The ban on hate speech. It is forbidden to incite unrest, to coerce people to harm or kill others. All freedoms end where the freedoms of others begin. Freedom of speech just means you can say "this guy is wrong", but you can't say "kill this guy". While Holocaust denial is "this is wrong", it's almost always followed up with "kill these guys" type of speech.

Comment: Holocaust don't happen. Let's kill jews (Joking. Just showing how absurd it is).

Comment: If I don't put "joking" I would be in jail if I were in germany?